# OnClick makes scrollTop equal zero for a moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navigation, fixed

I've added some simple animated scrolling to my website, however there's a little quirk with this in jQuery. I `slideDown()` a `.nav-fixed` navigation bar whenever the website's window top is under a static `.nav` navigation from the top of the website. Everything's fine except that when you click on any link (I assume any link with jQuery onClick animated scroll function) the `.nav-fixed` hides momentarily and shows up again after the website scrolls. I'm console logging a message `Should hide the nav` whenever the the top static `.nav` is in the window view and noticed that even when we're on the bottom of the page and click on any onclick jquery function link on the website the message gets logged once as if the static navigation was in the window view.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve that?
Here's the mentioned website: http://www.mmsmsy.com
Here's the code:

```
const addClickToNav = (element) => {
  $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 50}, 1000);
}

$('.nav-link-top').on('click', () => $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000));
$('.link-start').on('click', () => addClickToNav('.about'));
$('.nav-link-skills').on('click', () => addClickToNav('.skills'));
$('.nav-link-portfolio').on('click', () => addClickToNav('.portfolio'));
$('.nav-link-contact').on('click', () => addClickToNav('.contact'));

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.nav').offset().top + $('.nav').height() + 50 && $('.nav-fixed').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('.nav-fixed')
        .css('display', 'flex')
        .hide()
        .slideDown();
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('.nav').offset().top + $('.nav').height() + 50) {
        console.log("Should hide the nav");
        $('.nav-fixed').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did u try like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.nav').offset().top + $('.nav').height() + 50 && $('.nav-fixed').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('.nav-fixed')
        .css('display', 'flex')
        .hide()
        .slideDown();
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('.nav').offset().top + $('.nav').height() + 50) 
    {
        console.log("Should hide the nav");
        $('.nav-fixed').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did You just add the ```else``` keyword before the second ```if``` statement? If so, then no, it doesn't make any difference. If I missed any other changes You've made, please point it out as I don't see any.